# splitting a label that contains text and numbers

Tags: c#, label

I have a label containing the following text: "hat $15".

I want to split the text to 2 labels so that the word "hat" will go into label1 and the word "$15" will go into label2.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: You've given no indication of what programming language you're using.

Comment: C#? As it says in the tags?

Comment: Well you can use client side [`Split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) or by using string split on the server side, but did you try to even search for your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] data = label1.Text.Split(' ');
label2.Text = data[0];
label3.Text = data[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for this particular function.

Comment: Well, Microsoft gives a good example on how to split strings using this method. I feel that it would be somewhat redundant to expand on such a basic concept. :)

Comment: I know, it just struck me funny your answer was the only one not containing sample code :-)

Comment: Ack, yes! It's the curse of the future of copy-and-paste!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
string[] strings = label1.Text.Split(' ', 2);
label2.Text = strings[0];
label3.Text = (strings.Length > 1) ? strings[1] : String.Empty;
```

The second label is only filled if there's at least one space character in the original label's text.

The original label's text is split into exactly two parts even if there's more than one space character in the text. For example "Hello World: Test" will be split into "Hello" and "World: Test".

Answer (score 0):

use String.Split():

```
string s = "hat $15";
string[] items = s.Split(' ');
```